# Teams BOT install parameters.. How do I setup install parameters(APIKey, URL)

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I am working on a Teams Chat BOT with a developer.  This BOT is for multiple clients. .   When I install the BOT I want the BOT to ask the client for a URL and an API Key so it can get its data securely.

I really don't want the admin user to have to go into Azure and setup stuff (if possible).  I  want it to be like when installing a team app. It can display a parameter page and ask all sorts of questions.  (The WebSite app for example asks for a URL)

My developer says there is no way to do this.  Is there local config storage with a BOT?

Can the first use of the bot ask the questions(API Key, URL)  and store the answers?

Can a BOT get config data from sharepoint?

Other ideas??  Pointers to an example?  I looked everywhere and can't find docs or an approach to this problem.

I was hoping tha t installing a BOT would be the same as installing a Channel App with regards to questions.  I cannot find an approach or any examples that solve the problem and dont cause clients to need to setup an Azure service when they install the BOT